# Data Studio Cannot Sum Numbers to Chart

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field, google-search-console, web-analytics-tools, google-my-business

I need help to create a chart of sum multiple sources in Google Data Studio. My sources are:

- Google Search Console: `Clicks`
- Google My Business: `Phone Calls`, `Website Visits`, and `Direction Requests`

**Problem**

The chart is not SUM-ing those numbers. See image below, the green line `Combined Actions` should be the SUM of all the 4 metrics I mentioned above. FYI I renamed the parameters to help me differentiate:

- Site Search Clicks = GSC `Clicks`
- Tebet Phone Calls = GMB `Phone Calls`
- Tebet Website Visits = GMB `Website Visits`
- Tebet Direction Requests = GMB `Direction Requests`

[image: data studio chart not summing]

This is the formula I use

```
SUM(Clicks+Phone calls+Directions requests+Website visits)
```

[image]

This is the data source

[image]

I thought it was the number format that was corrupted, but if that's the case then why the individual chart is shown correctly? I can also draw each individual chart using `SUM(Clicks)`, `SUM(Phone calls)`, etc.

---

For Your Information, I have another chart in this page that works by summing:

- Google Search Console: `Impressions`
- Google My Business: `Direct search impressions`
  So those 2 data metrics are working well.
  [image]

Any help would be appreciated. Also let me know if you need any more context on this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to having `NULL` values (if there is no data for a single Metric at a single date in the [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583212) function, then that entire date row will be displayed as 0 in the [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart); one approach is to incorporate the [`IFNULL`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10521929) function below which treats `NULL` values as the numeric literal 0:

```
SUM(IFNULL(Clicks, 0) + IFNULL(Phone Calls, 0) + IFNULL(Directions Requests, 0) + IFNULL(Website Visits, 0))
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c7b668c5-d195-4779-9209-638c02db2d54) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVilvpC0DbDY6rNL9xZXukc-CpM-B_Eja6RVbvWX1co/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]